# How to read line chart data from blurry image

Tags: graph, data-extraction, linegraph

I've got an assignment where I need to read data points from an image of a line graph and write them to a csv file. The image is, however, pretty low-res and the data points are difficult to tell apart from the chart line itself, even to the human eye. Now, my question is how you would approach solving this problem because I don't have any idea on a framework I could use and I haven't found any similar projects to look at.

My goal is not that you write the code for me but that you share your thoughts on how you would approach this or any similar projects or frameworks that could be helpful as resources to look at. The language doesn't matter too much, however c#, Java or Python would be preferred.

Below, I've included an example of the graph; the lines are very blurry and the data points are difficult to make out. The horizontal axis represents months with gaps of two months and the vertical axis shows logarithmic USD-values.

[image: a small sample of the graph]

The output should look like this:

[image: what the output should look like]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
LOOP over x ( horizontal )pixels ( there are 250 in your image )
   LOOP over y ( vertical ) pixels
       IF x,y pixel is blue
            SAVE y value
   END LOOP over y pixels
   CALCULATE median of saved y values
   CALCULATE tx time of x
   CALCULATE vy value of median y
   SAVE tx, vy
END LOOP over x
CHOOSE reasonable point count N
CALCULATE inc = x range / N
FOR x = 0; x < x range; x += inc
    OUTPUT tx, vy
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also thought about just distributing my own points along the graph. Appreciate you taking your time and writing such a detailed snippet.

Comment: Aight, talked to the professor today, he said distributing my own points is totally fine and that the assignment is basically impossible with the data provided. As long as you try to come up with a solution he'll be happy, so I'll just distribute some points and go from there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.  An upvote is always appreciated.